# Silverlight Application screen resolution Issue

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I developed Silverlight application under 1280x1024 screen resolution Its look and feel is good in this(1280x1024) resolution.. But under 1024x768 screen resolution looks badly.
please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you create your components inside a canvas or you simple drag and dropped then into the xaml page. If this is the case then the layout will be affected by resolution changes.

To solve this problem you should put all your components inside one (or usually more than one) stack panel and align the controls (left, right, height, width, etc...) in relation to the stack panel.

It is not difficult to do it but it may take a little bit of time and effort to get familiar with it. But I can guarantee you that the result is well worth the effort.

VERY IMPORTANT: To space the controls (and the stack panels) between thenselfs and the borders, always use the Margins properties.

Silverlight is great in this aspect. An application developed using this aproach can work very well in different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your Early Reply.. I used Grid Control For Placing the Control.. I given Width and Everything.. Its not Drag and Drop..